# How to delete SuperSu and changes it made

Tags: file-system

I inherited a Moto G3 which I unlocked and installed TWRP and a custom ROM. I foolishly attempted to install SuperSu. It supposedly changes some system files.  Now I want it off the phone. In any event, there is no obvious way for me to uninstall SuperSu and system files which were changed.

I did some Internet research. One site said I had to reinstall the stock recovery and ROM. That sounds like a lot of extra effort, and I don't think any changes got made to TWRP. As far as I can determine, any changes took place in the System partition.

My question is this:

*Would it work for me to boot to recovery and use TWRP to do an advanced wipe of the Dalvik Cache, Data, Cache, and System partitions?*

Yes, I know then I need to reinstall the ROM and GAPPS. That's OK, I did not make many changes I need to retain.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. SuperSU installs itself "systemless-ly" on Android 6 or up.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed "SuperSu.zip" using TWRP Flashing, then you can also uninstall it by flashing the [uninstall.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=4410561&d=1517853382)